# Http failure response for http://localhost:3003/register/registerObjectData/: 404 Not Found

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, http, controller

I am creating a register page where i accept few details and store it in mongoDB. However, there must be some error which i am unable to follow. I am able to retrieve the data from the UI properly. And then i route this data via server.js to app.controller.js and from there to app.service.js.

I get error -

```
 POST http://localhost:3003/register/registerObjectData/ 404 (Not Found)
```

And this is my code. Please help me figure out my mistake -

**app.component.ts**

```
    register(registerData){
    console.log("inside Register()");


      this.registerObjectData = {
      'userName': registerData.userName,
      'email': registerData.email,
      'firstPassword': registerData.firstPassword,
      'repeatPassword': registerData.repeatPassword,
      'phone': registerData.phone,
      'company':registerData.company
     }


  this.http.post("http://localhost:3003/register/registerObjectData/" 
  , JSON.stringify(this.registerObjectData))
            .map(Response => Response)

            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("err =", err)
                return Observable.throw(err);

            })
            .subscribe((res: Response) => {

                console.log("XXXXXXXXX Register  Response ", res);

    })

  }
```

**server.js**

```
 var express = require('express');
 var cors = require('cors');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 //more definitions and var

 app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server on port ' + app.get('port'));
 });

app.use('/register', require('./api-mine-server/controller/register- 
controller.js'));
```

**app.controller.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var userService = require('../service/registerService');
var app = express();


router.post('/registerObjectData/:registerObjectData', registerUser);


module.exports = router;


function registerUser (req, res){

    console.log("registerUser , BODY IS, JSON.parse,req ", JSON.parse(req.params.registerObjectData));


    userService.registerUser(req,res)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log("data after registration = ",data)
        if(data == 'Registration Successful.'){
            var set = {
                data : data
            }
            res.send(set);
        }
        else{
            res.send(data);
        }

    })
    .catch(function (err) {

        res.status(400).send('Something went wrong. Status 400');
    });
}
```

Comment: problem in your route verify your path.

Comment: problem in your route verify your path `/register/registerObjectData/` and `/registerObjectData/:registerObjectData`. `registerObjectData` must be in register folder and also you not pass any key in url then remove `:registerObjectData` this because this is post request not get request